# PowerShell script to send an email with SQL results in HTML format

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, powershell, command-line

Does anyone have a PowerShell script to query results from a SQL Server database and send it out as an email in HTML format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following is a script I use to send query results in an HTML-formatted email.  Basically pipe the result of `invoke-sqlcmd` to `ConvertTo-Html` and then to `Out-String`, and then massage it a bit to get the table to display nicely.  If you don't add the padding style, everything will run together.

`Send-MailMessage` example below is for unathenticated, so if you have to authenticate to your SMTP server you'll need to fix that up

```
$Alerts = invoke-sqlcmd -ServerInstance dbserver -Database dbname -Query "SELECT * FROM some_table" | SELECT Severity, ServerName, Heading | ConvertTo-Html | Out-String
$Alerts = $Alerts.Replace("</head>", "<style> TD {padding-left: 2mm}</style></head>")
Send-MailMessage -To me@mycompany.com -From me@mycompany.com -BodyAsHtml $Alerts -Subject "Alerts" -SmtpServer "smtp.mycompany.com"
```

Comment: Thank you so much Tony for that input, that was exactly what i was looking for appreciate it!